# How to manage databases depending on the environment?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, database-migration, application.properties

Here, i have different databases for different environments

application-local.properties: `databasename: mylocaldb`

application-dev.properties: `databasename: mydevdb`

application-qa.properties:  `databasename: myqadb`

application-prod.properties: `databasename: myproddb`

and in migration scripts, in V1_users.sql, i have

CREATE TABLE `**databasename**`.`usertable`(--relevant code--);

So, How do i assign this database name depending on the environment active i.e local/dev/qa/prod

Comment: Can't you just _not_ specify the schema name, and use `create table usertable` directly?

Comment: Alternatively the same reasoning behind "infrastructure as code" and use the same name in every environment and only switch the connection via properties file.

Comment: @Smutje im not talking about switching connections...i just want to pass the database name in application.properties file explicitly regardless of the datasource.url and then access that database name in migration scripts

Comment: @sp00m i added the schema name to handle multiple databases

Comment: That's why it reads "Alternatively" - because it's easier to let your application run regardless of the database and configure it outside of your application.

Comment: @Smutje what if i have to keep different names for the databases?

Comment: Drop the database-name from the scripts

Comment: then how will it know what database to use?

Comment: Because you specify it in your properties file